# Sorting big csv file with pandas-groupby and use function .mean()

Tags: python, csv, pandas-groupby

I have a big csv file with 3 columns and lots of lines. 
It looks something like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjSM7.jpg)

Now I would like to have all the lines with ID1 grouped and get the mean of their values in C.

My code for this looks like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=";",decimal=",", index_col=0)

grouped = df.groupby(['A'])[['C']]
grouped.mean()
```

When running the code I get this Error:

But in the csv file I made sure that there are no NaN and no non-numerical values.

What can I do about this? Many Thanks!

> DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: What is the dtype of `df['C']`?

Comment: It says (non-null) object, I guess I need something like int64 or float 64, for the function .mean() to work, right? Is there a way that I can change the dtype without corrupting the data in 'C'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that your data types are non-numerical and can not be used by aggregating functions. Use

```
df.dtypes
```

to have a look on your data types. If they are not int/float, you have to convert them:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(float)
```

and perform the groupby afterwards